# Generate error not working with AsyncBuilder

Tags: flutter

I'm following https://recipes.tst.sh/docs/architecture/safe-async.html for the [asyncBuilder](https://github.com/PixelToast/async_builder) package. I'm trying to generate the error method. For some reason, it's not working and on error the builder run...

```dart
AsyncBuilder(
        future: fetchData(),
        error: (context, error, stackTrace) {
          print('in error');
          return Text('some error');
        },
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          print('in builder');
          print(snapshot); // prints out the error which the fetchData function returned in the catch statement
          return Container();
        });
```

```dart
Future<Response> fetchData() async {
    try {
      final responseJson = await _provider.get('data'); // throws error
      ...
      return Response.success(parsedData);
    } catch (e) {
      // This is called
      return Response.error(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

I tried throwing an error in the catch statement instead of returning one, but then the app crashed

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `throw Exception('Failed from fetchData ${e.toString()}');` 
code snippet

```
try {
  var response = await http
      .post("not exist", body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'});
  return http.Response("OK", 200);
} catch (e) {
  throw Exception('Failed from fetchData ${e.toString()}');
}

...
AsyncBuilder(
      future: fetchData(),
      error: (context, error, stackTrace) {
        print('in error');
        return Text('some error $error');
      },
```

working demo for success and error

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:async_builder/async_builder.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<http.Response> fetchData() async {
    try {
      var response = await http
          .post("not exist", body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'});
      return http.Response("OK", 200);
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed from fetchData ${e.toString()}');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: AsyncBuilder(
          future: fetchData(),
          error: (context, error, stackTrace) {
            print('in error');
            return Text('some error $error');
          },
          builder: (_, snapshot) {
            print('in builder');
            print(snapshot);
            return Text("success ${(snapshot as http.Response)?.body}");
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a `_Exception (Exception: Not Found: Not found)`

Comment: and the app freezes until i continue in the debugger